# getting string from pandas Series and DataFrames in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe in pandas:

```
d=pandas.DataFrame([{"a": 1, "b": 1}, {"c": 2, "b": 4}])
d["name"] = ["Hello", "World"]
```

I want to select an element based on its string value in "name" column and then get the value as a string. To select the element:

```
d[d["name"] == "World"]["name"]
Out:
1    World
Name: name
```

The problem is that it doesn't give a simple string but a series. Casting to a string won't help -- how can I just get the string `"World"` out of this? Is this the only way?

```
d[d["name"] == "World"]["name"].values[0]
```

thanks.

Comment: Could you expand on your example a bit?  Right now, it seems like you're putting "World" in and are looking to get "World" as an output.

Comment: @DSM: yes, that's correct, but imagine that instead of taking "name" we took a different col name, like: `d[d["name"] == "World"]["other_name"]` where `other_name` is a string column

Comment: That would have been a better example to give. :^)  But in the general case, there's no guarantee that there's only one matching value, right?  So I suspect that the result is going to be fundamentally array-like.  You can shorten the syntax -- using `max`, for example, or `iget` -- but other than that I'm not sure.  Maybe Hayden will have something clever..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As @DSM points out, in general there could be many rows with name `'World'`, so somewhere down the line we'll need to pick one.

One way to do this which seems kind of nice could be to use `where` (and then [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.max.html)):

```
In [11]: d.name.where(d.name == 'World', np.nan)
Out[11]: 
0      NaN
1    World
Name: name, dtype: object

In [12]: d.name.where(d.name == 'World', np.nan).max()
Out[12]: 'World'
```

*Note: if there is no row with name 'World' this will return NaN.*

Comment: I've wondered in the past if maybe there should be -- or maybe there is and I just don't know the syntax! -- a dict-like filter method, so that  something like `d.ff({"name": "World"})["c"]` would give the matching series, without the need to duplicate ".name" or "d".

Comment: @DSM I don't *think* there is (just had a look, will looks some more), but I agree that'd be quite a nice method, maybe should also take boolean functions on columns... I think I will add one. :)

Answer (score 26):

There's one method that no one mentioned that might be worth noting. This was a problem I was having where I was doing multiple criteria checks and getting back a single item Series (basically a unique row result). If you have a single item in a Series and just need that item OR know the index of the particular item you want to gather, just do this:

```
d[d["name"] == "World"].tolist()[0]
```

for the first (and only) item in a single item Series.

Or this:

```
d[d["name"] == "World"].tolist()[index]
```

where `index` is the index of the item you are looking for in the Series.

If you want it as a string, you may have to cast as a string if it is not already stringified by default.

Comment: thanks for the share. I cant believe there is not an easier function to call.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: Not recommended as it truncates long text unless using pandas > 1.0  (not tested)

Not sure what versions of Pandas this works in, but its one other option:

```
d[d["name"] == "World"].to_string(index=False)
```

and if more than one row there are other options:

```
 max_rows      int, optional
```

Maximum number of rows to show before truncating. If None, show all.

```
 min_rows      int, optional
```

The number of rows to display in a truncated repr (when number of rows is above max_rows).

Comment: No! The [to_string()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html) function exists to _display_ a DataFrame in a terminal friendly string representation. It will e.g. shorten long strings when used on a single field and is totally unsuited for OPs case.

Comment: Agreed, have added a comment just in case anyone thinks about using it